# Feathered erasing CGContextRef using UIBezierPath

Tags: objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I am erasing drawing from CGContextRef using UIBezierPath and CGBlendMode : kCGBlendModeClear. I am erasing the stroke path with line width 20. It left the path harsh. Is there any way to achieve feathered stroke for erasing drawing from CGContextRef.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
    UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] firstObject];
    [drawingPath moveToPoint:[self getConvertedPoint:touch]];
    currentPathData.drawingPath.lineJoinStyle =  kCGLineJoinMiter;  
      CGContextSetLineWidth(_imageContext,  currentPathData.line_width);    
}

-(CGPoint)getConvertedPoint:(UITouch *)touch{
    CGSize size = CGSizeMake(self.image.size.width * self.image.scale, self.image.size.height * self.image.scale);
    CGPoint touchPoint =  [touch locationInView:self];
    touchPoint = fromUItoQuartz(touchPoint, self.bounds.size);
    touchPoint = scalePoint(touchPoint, self.bounds.size, size);
    return touchPoint;
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
    if(_shouldDrawImage){
        if(!self.image){
            return ;
        }
        UITouch *touch = [[touches allObjects] firstObject];
        const CGPoint line_point = [self getConvertedPoint:touch];
        [drawingPath  addLineToPoint:line_point];
        UIImage *image = [self drawStrokeImage:line_point];
        [super setImage:image];
    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet<UITouch *> *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    [super touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
    _shouldDrawImage = NO;
    brushImageView.hidden = YES;
}

-(UIImage *)drawStrokeImage:(const CGPoint)line_point{
    CGContextSetBlendMode(_imageContext, blendMode);
    CGContextAddPath(_imageContext, [drawingPath CGPath]);
    CGContextStrokePath(_imageContext);    
    CGImageRef cgImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(_imageContext);
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:cgImage];
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return image;
}
```

I get this result from the above, I can not figure out how to apply feather in stroke path:

[image: I get this result from the above, I can not figure out how to apply feather in stroke path]

Comment: You are from IPvision Canda Inc.?  It looks like you can't even type your own company name.  What a shame...

Comment: I am new here, thank you for your kind review on my mistake.